# How to get all the nodes from CT.CustomTreeCtrl in wxpython

Tags: wxpython

I have created a tree using CT.CustomTreeCtrl in wxpython. Now I want read all the children in the tree. My tree structure is like a->b->c, where a is root node, b is child of a and parent of c.

When I use 'GetFirstChild(root)' I do get the child node 'b'. But I want to read the text of c. Any lead to this is appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a method similar to this in the past. This iterates through each item in the parent node and recursively yields every item that has children.

```
def get_all_nodes(self, parent_node):
    for child in parent_node.GetChildren():
        if self.ItemHasChildren(child):
            yield child
            for grandchild in self.get_all_nodes(child):
                yield grandchild
```

**Edit:**
to get each items' text use the method 'GetItemText'

```
def get_all_nodes(self, parent_node):
    for child in parent_node.GetChildren():
        if self.ItemHasChildren(child):
            yield self.GetItemText(child)
            for grandchild in self.get_all_nodes(child):
                yield self.GetItemText(grandchild)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it returns generator objects of all children. I want to get the names of each children and compare

Comment: It still return generator object. I'm not sure how to get the name from it.

Comment: I got it by using following code,
`c = root.GetChildren()
 for item in c:
     if testType != item.GetText():
         continue
     t = item.GetChildren()
     j = 0
     while j < len(t):
         curTest = t[j].GetText()
         if testName == curTest:
              self.tree.CheckItem(t[j], checked = True)
              j = j + 1`

Comment: you should look up a tutorial on generator objects